# Having trouble positioning elements in responsive 798px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this website www.lifeofaris.se/tree and on desktop view everything is fine but i cant figure out how to position my logo and text on the left in tablet dimension 798px. Whenever i move my elements on the tablet they will be moved also in desktop and i dont want that, can anyone help me?

Here is my code (index.html,framework.css,responsive.css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Electrolize' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">      
  <title>NK Electrical LTD</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <header>
         <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/nklogo.png" alt="NK Logo">
         </div>
         <h1 class="name">ELECTRICAL LTD</h1>
         <div class="box">
         <div class="info">
         <p class="fb">Follow us on <a href="http://facebook.com/nkelectricalltd"><img src="img/fb.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a></p>
         <p class="emergency">Emergency-call-number:2222222</p>
         </div>
             </div>
         <a id="i-nav" href="#"></a>
         <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="electrical.html">Elec. Installations</a></li>
                <li><a href="lighting.html">Lighting</a></li>
                <li><a href="appliances.html">Home Appliances</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
      </nav> 
     </header>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="slider">
             <a href="img/wormhole.jpg">
            <img src="img/wormhole.jpg" alt="slider">
             </a>
         </div>
         <section class="boxes">
        <ul id="gallery">
          <li>
            <a href="img/electrical.png">
              <img src="img/electrical.png" alt="">
              <p>Electrical Installations</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/lighting.png">
              <img src="img/lighting.png" alt="">
              <p>Lighting Decorations</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/homeappliances1.png">
              <img src="img/homeappliances1.png" alt="">
              <p>Electrical Appliances</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/homeappliances2.png">
              <img src="img/homeappliances2.png" alt="">
              <p>Kitchen Appliances</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
        <section class="latest">
            <h1>Our latest products</h1>
         <ul id="galleryproducts">
          <li>
            <a href="img/1.jpg">
              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/2.jpg">
              <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/3.jpg">
              <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="img/4.jpg">
              <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
         </section>
     </div>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; NK ELECTRICAL LTD 2016</p>
      </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Framework.css/main

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;}
.container{
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a{text-decoration: none;}
header{
    margin: 0 0 1% 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
.logo{text-align: center;padding:0;width:50%;margin:0 auto;}
.logo img{width:50%}
nav{
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0% 2%;
}
nav li {
    background-color: #656565;
    margin:5% 0% 5% 0%;
    display: block;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 5% 10%;
}
.slider{width:100%;padding: 0;margin: 0 auto;}
#gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0% -2.7% 0% -2.7%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
#gallery li:nth-child(3n) {clear: left;}
#gallery li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  background-color: #483636;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  text-align:center;
}
#gallery img{max-width: 100%; padding:10%;}
#galleryproducts{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}
#galleryproducts li{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin:0 10% 2% 10%;
}
#galleryproducts li:nth-child(3n) {
    clear: both;
}
.logo img{width:100%;max-width:120px;}
.latest{clear:both;background-color:#1c1c1c;}
.latest h1{color: white;font-size:1.5em;font-weight: 300;border-bottom: 3px solid white;margin-bottom: 5%;padding:2%;}
.latest img{max-width: 100%;}
#galleryproducts img{border:3px solid white;}
.slider{clear:both;}
.slider img{max-width: 100%;}
footer{clear:both;text-align: center; margin-top:5%;padding:3.1%;background-color:#1c1c1c;}
footer p{color:white;font-size:0.8em;font-weight: 900;}
.name{font-size: 1.3em;font-weight: 900;margin-bottom: 10%;text-align: center;}
.info{background-image: url(../img/image.png); text-align: center;color:white;}
.fb{font-size:1.3em;}
.fb img {width:8%;}
.emergency{font-size:1.3em;padding:5%;}
.show{margin-top:3%;display: block !important;}
 #i-nav{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width:44px;
    height:44px;
    background-image: url("../img/ham.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;}

Responsive.css

@media screen and (min-width: 798px) {
    .container{max-width: 990px;}
    .box{float:right;position: relative;}
    .logo{clear: both;}
    .logo img{width:100%; max-width:92px;}
    #i-nav{
        display: none;
    }
    nav{
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul{
        padding:0;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        width:350px;
        margin:1% 2% 1% 2%;
    }
    nav a{
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding:10%;
    }
    .logo{float:left;width:500px;height:0;}
    .name{clear: both;margin:0;height:0;}
    .box{}
    .info {background-image: url(../img/social.png);background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;width:529px;padding-top: 11%; padding-bottom: 11%;}
    .fb img{width:15%;}
    .fb, .emergency{position: absolute;top:36px;right:1px;}
    .emergency{margin-top:3%;}
    .slider{max-width: 85%;}
    #gallery{max-width:100%;margin:0 auto;text-align: center;}
    #gallery li{width:40%;margin-right:-20px;margin-left: 65px;}
    .boxes{margin-top: -1%}
    .latest{max-width:85%;margin:0 auto;}
    footer p{font-size: 1.2em;}
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1290px){
    header{width:1009px;margin:0 auto;}
    .container{max-width:1344px;}
    .logo img{float:left;width:400px;margin-top:2%;}
    .name{float:left; margin-top: 6.5%;
    margin-left: 9%;}
    .info{ width:500px;float:right;margin:0 auto;}
    .slider{max-width: 83.5%;}
    nav a{padding: 20% 0% 18% 0%;
    font-size: 1em;}
     nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0% 0.9% 0% 0.1%;
        padding:0;
        width:15%;}
    #gallery{text-align: center;}
    #gallery li{margin-left:0;margin-right:0.9%;float:none;display:inline-block;width:20%;} 
    #gallery li:nth-child(1n) {margin-right:6.2px;margin-left:4.0px;}
    .latest{max-width: 83.4%;}
    #galleryproducts li{float:none;width:18%;display: inline-block;margin:2.3%;}
    #galleryproducts li:nth-child(1n) {margin-left:4%;}
    footer p{font-size: 1.2em;}
}
```

Comment: you need to reduce your code example to demonstrate the problem - currently there could be allsorts in there contributing and SO isn't a debugging service. Try creating a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that emphasises the problem so it can be seen clearly

Comment: why `.logo` div height is 0

Comment: so it can get on the same level as the "box", cant think other way

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y06nzgob/ or www.lifeofaris.se/tree